# Prolog retract doesn't change database

Tags: database, prolog

### #Retract doesn't change the database#

Hi i have a database in Prolog consisting of simple facts:

```
:-dynamic sportsmen/2.
sportsmen('Andrew', 'Shaw').
sportsmen('Patrick', 'Kane').
```

Now i want to retract some facts from it. Problem is, when i call 
  `retract(sportsmen(_,'Kane'))`
it returns true, but there is no change in my database, i tried to find a solution here and i found some guy that has this problem a was adviced to look at predicate tell/1. I know what this predicate is doing but i cant figure out how can i write back to database all the remaining facts excepts of the one i want to delete.

*Can anyone help*?

Comment: How did you verify that the retract did not work?  Which version of Prolog are you using?

Comment: I want to achieve that on my file there will be just this
    :-dynamic sportsmen/2.
    sportsmen('Andrew', 'Shaw').
But when i try to retract, there is no change in it.
I am using SWI prolog

Comment: You are trying to EDIT a text file?

Comment: You do know that assert/retract only affects the database in memory - it won't affect facts retrieved from a file, right ?  So are you pulling in the facts from a file / need to save them to a file, or can everything be done in memory ?

Comment: yes i am trying to EDIT but not the text file but a .pl file

Comment: A .pl file IS a text file (you used a text editor to write it, didn't you?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retract works. It retracts from the database in memory. It does *not* remove facts from your file:

```
$ cat foo.pl

:-dynamic( sportsmen/2 ).

sportsmen('Andrew', 'Shaw').
sportsmen('Patrick', 'Kane').
```

Run prolog:

```
$ gprolog
GNU Prolog 1.4.2
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2012 Daniel Diaz
```

Load the `foo.pl` file:

```
| ?- [foo].
compiling /home/mark/src/prolog/_play_/foo.pl for byte code...
/home/mark/src/prolog/_play_/foo.pl compiled, 6 lines read - 398 bytes written, 13 ms

(1 ms) yes
```

Note that the facts are present:

```
| ?- listing.

% file: /home/mark/src/prolog/_play_/foo.pl

sportsmen('Andrew', 'Shaw').
sportsmen('Patrick', 'Kane').

(1 ms) yes
```

Retract one of the facts:

```
| ?- retract(sportsmen(_, 'Kane')).

yes
```

Note that the fact was retracted:

```
| ?- listing.

% file: /home/mark/src/prolog/_play_/foo.pl

sportsmen('Andrew', 'Shaw').

yes
```

Exit prolog:

```
| ?- ^D
```

Note that the facts are still all present in the file:

```
$ cat foo.pl

:-dynamic( sportsmen/2 ).

sportsmen('Andrew', 'Shaw').
sportsmen('Patrick', 'Kane').
```

---

If you want to maintain some facts in a file, you would do your database manipulation in memory, as shown above, and then use Prolog file I/O predicates to write out the updated facts. For example, to save a given set of `sportsmen` facts, using the Edinburgh style I/O predicates:

```
telling(OldStream),
tell('sportsmen.pl'),
write(':- dynamic sportsmen/2.'), nl,
listing(sportsmen),
told,
tell(OldStream).
```

Comment: how can i remove the facts than?

Comment: @user3568104 I updated the answer with a little info showing one way to do that.

Comment: @user3568104 then you should accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark on the left near the top of the answer.